# Usage of "note (bill)" and "banknote" in AmE

Tags: differences, nouns, american-english

Do American English speakers use *note* to mean *bill* (as in *ten-dollar bill*)?  If so, is *note* a shortening of the word *banknote*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While AmE speakers would understand *note* if used in context, *bill* is substantially more common among the general population.  Asking someone if they have a *twenty-dollar note* just sounds odd to my AmE ears.

I believe usage of the term *note* is more common in professions that deal specifically with currency (e.g. banking, treasury, etc.), and I'll, *ahem*, note that US currency actually is labeled as a *Federal Reserve Note* and includes the phrase *This note is legal tender*. However, in some financial circles, you run the risk of being confused with other types of notes, e.g. a *Treasury note* (*T-Note*).

And yes, *note* is short for *banknote*.

Answer (score 3):

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ten%20-%20dollar%20bill,ten%20-%20dollar%20note&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) graphs the usages of *ten-dollar bill* and *ten-dollar note*:

[image]

*Bill* is much more common than *note*; you will not hear normal American conversation include the term *note* in referring to a ten-dollar bill.  When *ten-dollar note* is used in American English, it is usually a numismatic term, a formal term, or else foreign currency.

*Note* is *[banknote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknote)* abbreviated:

> A **banknote** (often known as a **bill**, **paper money** or simply a **note**) is a kind of negotiable instrument, a promissory note made by a bank payable to the bearer on demand, used as money, and in many jurisdictions is legal tender.

Answer (score 1):

*Note* is rarely—if ever—used as an abbreviation for *banknote*. The colloquial use of *note* in American English refers to debt instruments such as *promissory notes*, *deeds of trust*, etc. For example, savvy property companies will often try to "purchase the note" on a property going into foreclosure; this allows them to foreclose on the property themselves, avoiding some of the risk of bidding at the auction: even if someone else wins it, instant profit.

Comment: -1, that's exactly what "note" refers to in this context, a bank ote.

Comment: @Josh: a banknote is a type of debt instrument, but not one that has specific performance (ie, tied to a real asset, as opposed to fiat money).

Comment: [That's not what Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknote)... and the other answers also disagree.